# Schunk Arm URD COLLADA file is not a valid robot model

Tags: ros, urdf, moveit, collada, srdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to import Schunk arm using the setupAssistant in moveit!

But when I browse to the SchunkDescription and load the .urdf file, then the setupAssistant gives me the following message:
URDF/COLLADA file is not a valid robot model.

How to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165231/schunk-arm--urd-collada-file-is-not-a-valid-robot-model/) by [rvijay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18021/rvijay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am also using schunk arm in moveit.
I think you should first define a real arm with the given schunk description file, not only using macro part for the arm.

---

Originally posted by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) with karma: 90 on 2014-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0